# Codigo de barras em hexadecimal

Tags: php

Estou tentando gerar um hexadecimal para mandar um comando direto pra porta da impressora para gerar um código de barras, estou com dificuldade em gerar, comecei a fazer o comando para mandar, estava me baseando no comando do delphi e estou implementando no php mas esta me gerando uns comando diferente a impressora que estou testando a impressão direta é a MPT III.

```
$chave = "43160308421998000100550010000000051000000050";
$lch   = "";
$dec  = "";
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(20)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(20)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('1d')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(68)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(40)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('1d')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(77)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(02)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('1d')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(48)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(02)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('1d')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('6b')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(18)));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex('7d')));
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(43)));

$chaveasc = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($chave); $i++){

$lch .= $chave{$i};

if((($i+1) % 2 == 0) && ($i > 0)){
 //echo $lch.'<br/>';
 $dec .= chr((int)(dechex($lch)));

 $lch = "";
//echo $dec.'<br/>';  
}
}
$dec .= chr((int)(dechex(20)));

//echo $dec;
$fp = fopen("bloco1.txt", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp,$dec);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: [edit] a sua pergunta e adicione a alteração abaixo, da qual postou como resposta. Somente post como resposta se tiver resolvido. Assim poderemos te ajudar melhor. vlw

Comment: Resolvi sem ajuda obrigado